# Previous and next buttons that navigate through a single page

Tags: javascript, html

Still a noob but I am slowly getting there.
I have a series of divs, all the same class and I have previous and next buttons that scroll to the top of the next or previous div when clicked. I would like to set an offset so that my header won't hide the div that scrolls underneath of it and I am unsure how to go about this. Code below.

```
 <button class="prev link js-prev js-scroll-to">Previous</button>
 <button class="next link js-next">Next</button>
<script>
$('.js-scroll-to').click(function(e) {

    target = $($(this).attr('href'));

    if (target.offset()) {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top + 'px'}, 1000);
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});



$('.js-next').click(function(e) {

  var selected = $(".js-list-item.js-current-panel");
  var anchors = $(".js-list-item");

  var pos = anchors.index(selected);
  var next = anchors.get(pos+1);
  var prev = anchors.get(pos-1);
  
  target = $(next);
  
  $(selected).removeClass("js-current-panel");
  $(next).addClass("js-current-panel");
  
    if (target.offset()) {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top + 'px'}, 1000);
    }
 

    e.preventDefault();
});


$('.js-prev').click(function(e) {

  var selected = $(".js-list-item.js-current-panel");
  var anchors = $(".js-list-item");

  var pos = anchors.index(selected);
  var next = anchors.get(pos+1);
  var prev = anchors.get(pos-1);
  
  target = $(prev);
  
    $(selected).removeClass("js-current-panel");
  $(prev).addClass("js-current-panel");
  
  if (target.offset()) {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top + 'px'}, 1000);
    }
  
  
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, I think you could just add the offset right into your animated scroll code (subtracting the height of the nav bar plus a little margin):

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top - 54 + 'px'}, 1000);
```

I usually do this without a JS scroll by adding a span class to use as the anchor instead of anchoring on the div itself.  This will work if someone links directly to the anchor point as well.

That way I can use position relative on the anchor to set an offset for the height of the nav bar.

In this case, I think you probably have some divs like this:

```
<div class="js-list-item js-current-panel">
 content
</div>
<div class="js-list-item">
 content
</div>
<div class="js-list-item">
 content
</div>
```

I'd change it to:

```
<span class="anchor js-list-item js-current-panel"></span>
<div class="content">
 content
</div>
<span class="anchor js-list-item"></span>
<div class="content">
 content
</div>
<span class="anchor js-list-item"></span>
<div class="content">
 content
</div>
```

With some CSS to position those new anchors (top depends on nav bar height):

```
.anchor {
 position: relative;
 top: -54px;
}
```

Example with some extra CSS to show how the anchors are positioned:

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    background: black;
  }
  .main {
    margin-top: 54px;
  }
  .js-list-item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    top: -54px;
  }
  .content {
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
</style>
<div class="nav">
  <button class="prev link js-prev js-scroll-to">Previous</button>
  <button class="next link js-next">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <span class="js-list-item js-current-panel"></span>
  <div id="one" class="content">content</div>
  <span class="js-list-item"></span>
  <div id="two" class="content">content</div>
  <span class="js-list-item"></span>
  <div id="three" class="content">content</div>
  <span class="js-list-item"></span>
  <div id="four" class="content">content</div>
  <span class="js-list-item"></span>
  <div id="five" class="content">content</div>
  <span class="js-list-item"></span>
  <div id="six" class="content">content</div>
  <span class="js-list-item"></span>
  <div id="seven" class="content">content</div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  $('.js-scroll-to').click(function(e) {

    target = $($(this).attr('href'));

    if (target.offset()) {
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top + 'px'}, 1000);
    }

    e.preventDefault();
  });



  $('.js-next').click(function(e) {

    var selected = $(".js-list-item.js-current-panel");
    var anchors = $(".js-list-item");

    var pos = anchors.index(selected);
    var next = anchors.get(pos+1);
    var prev = anchors.get(pos-1);

    target = $(next);

    $(selected).removeClass("js-current-panel");
    $(next).addClass("js-current-panel");

    if (target.offset()) {
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top + 'px'}, 1000);
    }


    e.preventDefault();
  });


  $('.js-prev').click(function(e) {

    var selected = $(".js-list-item.js-current-panel");
    var anchors = $(".js-list-item");

    var pos = anchors.index(selected);
    var next = anchors.get(pos+1);
    var prev = anchors.get(pos-1);

    target = $(prev);

    $(selected).removeClass("js-current-panel");
    $(prev).addClass("js-current-panel");

    if (target.offset()) {
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top + 'px'}, 1000);
    }


    e.preventDefault();
  });
</script>
```